# Como permitir apenas números em um prompt em javascript?

Tags: javascript, prompt

Eu quero que eu consiga colocar somente números quando for inserir alguma coisa no prompt.

```
var count = prompt("Teste");
```

Como consigo fazer isso?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar uma versão de `prompt` para isso que insiste até que o usuário digite um número na forma que você queira:

```js
function promptInt(mensagem, tenteNovamente) {
    var msg = mensagem;
    while (true) {
        var ret = parseInt(prompt(msg));
        if (!isNaN(ret)) return ret;
        msg = tenteNovamente;
    }
}

var count = promptInt("Teste", "Por favor, digite um número.\nTente novamente.");
alert("Você digitou o número " + count + ".");
```

A função `isNaN` é usada para verificar se o usuário digitou um número ou não.